# image upload and preview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to browse image from client computer as soon as image is uploaded, it will display preview and when client(I) saves details, it will be saved in the database.
as well as that image will be displayed in page

I have fileuploader

```
<style type="text/css">
    #newPreview
    {
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(sizingMethod=scale);
    }
</style>
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css "
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js "></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function PreviewImg(imgFile) {
        if (navigator.appName != "Netscape") {
            var newPreview = document.getElementById("newPreview");
            newPreview.style.display = "";
            newPreview.filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = imgFile.value;
            newPreview.style.width = "250px";
            newPreview.style.height = "200px";
        }
        else {
            if (imgFile.files && imgFile.files[0]) {

                var reader = new FileReader();
                $('[id*=divFirfox]').css("display", "block");
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(250)
                .height(200);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(imgFile.files[0]);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

now what should i do to retrive image from database?
something like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419345/displaying-image-retrieved-from-database-to-image-control)

Comment: Why do you want to do all this stuff instead you have an asp.net image upload control which does what you need ?

Comment: i m new in asp.net and i have searched for display image for preview(before save image in database)

Comment: Something like 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419345/displaying-image-retrieved-from-database-to-image-control